# SQL 2008R2 Trial

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I currently have a small db running on SQL Server 2008R2 Express. I'm considering moving to SQL 2008R2 Small Business or Standard to use all the sever is capable of. I have a Dell T610 - 2xQuad Core Xeon E5540 2.53GHz - 30GB RAM, 4x146GB 15K SAS + 4x1TB Enterprise SATA- Perc 6/i RAID controller. Both sets configured for RAID 10. Running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.

My question is, if I load the SQL 2008R2 trial version and do not see the improvement I expect, can I easily move back to Express?

Just a note - I can not go to SQL 2012, the db app is limited to SQL 2008.